# BS5 Carousel broken, not interactive

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I am trying to include a bootstrap 5 carousel to my side, but the interactive part (prev/next button and the autosliding every couple of seconds) does not work - it only shows the first.

The carousel code is 100% copied from https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/components/carousel/ and *should* work. The same code is also used in the official docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/#with-captions

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">


</head>
<body>

<!-- Carousel wrapper -->
<div id="carouselBasicExample" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-mdb-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-mdb-target="#carouselBasicExample" data-mdb-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-mdb-target="#carouselBasicExample" data-mdb-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-mdb-target="#carouselBasicExample" data-mdb-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Inner -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <!-- Single item -->
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(15).jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."/>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>First slide label</h5>
        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Single item -->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(22).jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."/>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Second slide label</h5>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Single item -->
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(23).jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."/>
      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
        <h5>Third slide label</h5>
        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Inner -->

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselBasicExample" role="button" data-mdb-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselBasicExample" role="button" data-mdb-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
<!-- Carousel wrapper -->


<!-- Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

It seems like some kind of script is broken, dev tools does not show any error tho. The CDN links are the one recommended in the bootstrap 5 tutorial.

The script tag can be found at end of body.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap Carousel not working, does it need javascript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64149455/bootstrap-carousel-not-working-does-it-need-javascript-code)

Comment: I do add the JS at the end of `body` as described in https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#bundle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the fix: use `data-bs-..` instead of `data-mdb-...`

I followed the tutorial over at https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/components/carousel/ because the official docs were initially not working, unfortunately they used a different tag attribute. Changing all attributes fixed it.

Apparently MDBootstrap is a framework that slightly differs from bootstrap (not a fork, entirely written from scratch). The name is a bit misleading in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the official documentation of Bootstrap 5 here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/carousel/

It will work 100%.

**Update after your reply:**

For me (I tested it) it works like charm with this code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Carousel Bootstrap 5</title>

    <!-- Link to Bootstrap 5 CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>


    <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="one.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="two.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="three.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```